# How to do maximum RPS from net/http downstream calls in go

Tags: go

We have an application that talks to 6 downstream services hosted on k8s. The golang service is an orchestrator for the downstream services. During peak traffic we get around 800 requests per second requests per second. This requests then go to these 6 services using net/http. These are k8s namespace calls. During peak we see create http connection is throttling and latency for the go service increases.

Currently this is how we are making calls

```
const (
    maxIdleConnectionsPerHost = 800
    maxIdleConns              = 2000
)
type Client struct {
    *http.Client
}

func ConfigureHTTPClient(timeout time.Duration) *Client {
    t := http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).Clone()
    t.MaxIdleConnsPerHost = maxIdleConnectionsPerHost
    t.MaxIdleConns = maxIdleConns
     
    return &Client{
        &http.Client{Timeout: 10 * time.Second, Transport: t},
    }
}
```

Can some one help me configure this client, so that no connection is waiting. We have set a very high ulimit on our distro

Comment: Why do you set max idle conns to 0 if you want to be able to reuse them?

Comment: @JimB typo I have updated with actual numbers

Comment: What is the maximum number of concurrent requests you can have? Are you certain all requests are fully read and closed?

Comment: @JimB max concurrent we want is around 2000, all are getting closed using resp.Body.Close()

Comment: maxIdleConnectionsPerHost = 800
maxIdleConns              = 2000 this is current setup

Comment: Sorry, read that wrong. If you are not exceeding 800 concurrent connections per host, or 2000 total, then you should be ok. You would need dig deeper to figure out what is limiting you. 2000 clients could be excessive, and limiting the number might give better throughput. Are you making sure to read all responses too?

Comment: We are doing json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&data) for all requests. I know I am missing something. :(

Comment: @JimB the number of gorotines is always constant except for peak traffic

Comment: the responses could have extra unread data, maybe switch to reading the full response and unmarshaling it just to see if there is any difference? Other than that I’m out of guesses without more data, but it’s probably going to take some deeper profiling to see what is going on. It’s possible the client is just fine and the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @JimB thanks for all the help, will add pprof and see